# Improving my SELECTs that use PDO and adding an UPDATE statement

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, sql-update

I'm using the following code to select data from a MySQL table. Can someone tell me how to improve this as it seems a bit messy?

Also, I need to run an UPDATE statement to increment the value in the "views" column each time a customer is queried from the database. Each customer row in the database has a column named "views". For example, say ABC Corp has 100 views. If I search for ABC Corp and the database returns the record, the "views" column for this record should be updated to 101. What is the best way to do this?

```
if ($search && ($group && $group !== "*")) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE description LIKE :description AND groupId LIKE :groupId";
  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindValue(":description", "%" . $search . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $result->bindValue(":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
} else if ($search) {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE description LIKE :description";
  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindValue(":description", "%" . $search . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);
} else if ($group !== "*") {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers WHERE groupId LIKE :groupId";
  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $result->bindValue(":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
} else {
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers";
  $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about something like this,

```
 $sql = "SELECT * FROM customers ";
 $and = $grp = FALSE;

 if($search || ($group && $group !== "*") {
 $sql .= " WHERE ";
 if ($search) {
  $sql .= " description LIKE :description ";
  $and = TRUE;
 } 

 if ($group && $group !== "*") {
   if( $and === TRUE )
     $sql .= " AND ";        
   $sql .= " groupId LIKE :groupId ";  
   $grp = TRUE;     
 }     
 } 

 $result = $conn->prepare($sql);
 if( $and === TRUE)
  $result->bindValue(":description", "%" . $search . "%", PDO::PARAM_STR);

 if( $grp === TRUE)
   $result->bindValue(":groupId", $groupId, PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

For the `UPDATE` statement,

```
   //say $cust_name is the requested customer to be searched
   $sql = "SELECT views from customers where customer_name = '" $cust_name."'";
   $res = $conn->query($sql);
   $views = $res->fetchColumn() + 1;
   //sets 'views' to num_of_customers/rows returned.
   $sql = "UPDATE customers SET VIEWS = " .$views." WHERE customer_name = '" $cust_name."'";
   $res = $conn->query($sql);
```

Comment: Thanks. How could an UPDATE statement be added to it?

Comment: When you mean `each time a customer is queried`, do you mean the `SELECT` query that includes `groupId LIKE :groupId` ?

Comment: I mean anytime a "customer" row is returned in a SELECT statement. (i.e. SELECT * FROM customers).

Comment: Sorry, I don't think I was clear enough with my request. So each customer row in the database has a column named "views". Say ABC Corp has 100 views. If I search for ABC Corp and the database returns the record, the "views" column for this record should be updated to 101.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your help. That helped me tremendously!